# Show the menus for a window in the menu bar not working

Tags: 14.04

I am running Ubuntu 14.04. Recently I checked the option to show app menus "in the window's title bar". But now I want to restore it. Neither clicking the "Restore Behavior Settings", nor selecting "in the menu bar" works. Any ideas what is going wrong?

Take a look at the screenshot. As you see, in the appearance settings I selected showing menus in the menu bar, however the menus are shown in the application window.

[image]

http://postimg.org/image/gnxo6h877/full/

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Have you tried logging in again?

Comment: Could you please be more specific. Where exactly did you find the option?

Comment: I tried rebooting, it did not help. The option is sitting in System Settings -> Appearance -> Behavior tab.

Comment: Issue is solved. Looks like there were some packages missing. I installed indicator-appmenu and unity-gtk3-module, unity-gtk2-module, logged out and back in - it works now!